# What is most optimal way to replace integer '0' with '1' in c++

Tags: c++

I have a piece of code where I multiply two numbers but condition is none of those integer numbers should be 0. If it is 0, I need to make it to 1 so that it is not counted.

```
y=x*z // x>0, z>0. if x==0 then x=1, if z==0, then z=1;
```

I want to avoid "if" condition check on every variable and replace with 1. Is there a better way of doing it.

Comment: don't do this `x ? z ? x * z : x : z ? z : 1`

Comment: Are you trying to avoid an `if` at the syntactic level or you're weary of the branch in the generated machine code? Because all the solutions with the `?` are just hiding the branch under the rug (the `if` is still there, you just camouflaged it under different syntax).

Comment: What's wrong with: `assert(x != 0); assert(z != 0);` and making sure that the assertions never fire?  Put another way, why are you accepting bogus data?  Why not forcibly reject erroneous data?  And what's up with: `y = x * z; if (y == 0) y = 1;` which only checks the result, not the operands?  If the answer is that for `x == 0 && z == 2` the value in `y` should be 2, then you should say as much in the question.

Answer (score 15):

Below

```
y=(x==0?1:x)*(z==0?1:z)
```

will give you this [[ assembly ]](https://godbolt.org/g/dZi1uz) code.

---

and an adaption borrowed from [@Jerry Coffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179910/jerry-coffin)'s comment to his [[ answer ]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37936220/1620779)

```
y=(x+(x==0))*(z+(z==0));
```

will give you this [[ assembly ]](https://godbolt.org/g/detE6I) code.

Comment: Generates the smallest [Assembly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',source:'int+main(int+i,+char**g)%0A%7B%0A++int+x+%3D+*g%5B0%5D%3B%0A++int+z+%3D+*g%5B1%5D%3B%0A++return+(x%3D%3D0%3F1:x)*(z%3D%3D0%3F1:z)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

Comment: @Viatorus : Updated the answer. :)

Comment: I would recommend a further adaptation of your second line to `y=(x+!x)*(z+!z));`

Comment: @dberm22 : Thanks, will get back to this and keep you posted.

Answer (score 10):

```
y = (!x ^ x) * (!z ^ z);
```

This works because when you xor a number with 0, you get the same number back. So if `x != 0`, then `!x == 0`, and `!x ^ x` is equivalent to `0 ^ x`, which is `x`. And if `x == 0`, then `!x == 1`, and `!x ^ x` is equivalent to `1 ^ 0`, which is 1.

Comment: Plus 1 for meeting all the requirements, -999 for anyone who ever actually codes that in real life.

Comment: Needs two more xor-instruction in contrast to @sjsam. [Assembly](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',source:'int+main(int+i,+char**g)%0A%7B%0A++int+x+%3D+*g%5B0%5D%3B%0A++int+z+%3D+*g%5B1%5D%3B%0A++return+(!!x+%5E+x)+*+(!!z+%5E+z)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

Comment: @Viatorus: number of generated assembly instructions is often a useless metric as far as performance is concerned. Compilers have generally two mutually exclusive flags for fast vs small code.

Comment: Please don't use this solution as `!x` can be tricky and produce undefined result in this case. I'm saying this from personal experience.

Answer (score 6):

I honestly doubt that you could come up with a way that would be significantly underperforming. Pick something that you can read later instead of something that you believe will be the fastest. Chances are that this specific operation won't be a bottleneck.

Comment: Or he's looking for clear, concise code, in which case your commentary doesn't help much.

Comment: I challenge you to quantify the readability benefits of a "clear and concise" solution over the obvious two-conditionals solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm certainly not going to guarantee that it'll have any positive effects on your code, but one possibility would be something like this:

```
x += int(x == 0);
z += int(z == 0);
```

This compares the variable to 0, producing `false` or `true`. That's then converted to an `int`, giving `0` if the value was previously non-zero, and `1` if it was zero. We then add that result to the variable, so if it was zero, we'll add one, giving 1. If it was any non-zero value, we add zero to it, which obviously doesn't affect its value.

Comment: Nice, but I don't think the op actually wishes to change the variable here though they have mentioned `I need to make it to 1`. The change is just for the operation.

Comment: @CareyGregory : Nice!!

Comment: @sjsam: My mind reading extends only so far (but if that's really want they want, `x + (x==0)` should do the job).

Comment: @JerryCoffin : `x + (x==0)` will indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

```
y=max(x,1)*max(z,1);
```

Define max function if necessary by #define preprocessor keyword or as a normal function.

Answer (score 1):

If one of them is `0` then addition will give you same result as if you change  `0` to `1`

```
y = (x * z > 0 ? x * z : x + z)
```

Comment: The above will not work if x, or z is negative. It should be `y = ((x * z  == 0) ? x + z : x * z)`

Answer (score 1):

It will work

y=(x?x:1)*(z?z:1)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used link from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37936113/1237747) and created such code. [assembly here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O2',source:'int+main(int+i,+char**g)%0A%7B%0A+int+x+%3D+*g%5B0%5D%3B%0A++++++int+z+%3D+*g%5B1%5D%3B%0A++++++int+tmp+%3D+z+%3F+1+:+z%3B%0A++++++return+(x%3D%3D0%3Ftmp:x*tmp)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3), assembly is shorter, so might be faster, but needs profiling, because shorter assembly might not be faster.

```
int main(int i, char**g)
{
  int x = *g[0];
  int z = *g[1];
  int tmp = z ? 1 : z;
  return (x==0?tmp:x*tmp);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're concerned about precise results, then you should use the if statement you have in your comment or the ternary operator `?` as most people are suggesting.
If you simply care that there be no branches in this section of code you can always OR 1:

```
x = x | 1;
z = z | 1;
y = x * z;
```

This would guaranty that there would be no branches in this code and that neither `x` or `z` are every equal to `0`. But the price to pay is precision, since you could always accidentally add `1` to either `x` or `z`:

```
00000000 | 1 = 1
10001011 | 1 = 10001011
10101010 | 1 = 10101011 <- imprecision introduced!
```